# HiveQL stdev and group by issue

Tags: hiveql

Wondering about the Hive QL Stdev_pop -- this query works

```
select ip, sqrt(variance(time)) as stdev from logs group by ip
```

However, std deviation (which should be the same as above), give an error like;

```
select ip, stdev_pop(time) as stdev from logs group by ip;

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: 
                           Line 1:19 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'time'
```

I tried the stdev_sample as well with the same error.

Do anybody know why hive would expect group-by time?